# How to access request.session.get[] variable value in forms.py in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

**I want populate using request.session.get[] model choice field in  forms.py**
**form.py file**

```
class AssetTagForm(ModelForm):
    assets = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}) ,queryset=Asset.objects.filter(branch = self.session['branch']))
    class Meta:
        model = AssetTag
        fields = '__all__'
        labels = {
            'tag':'Asset Tag',
        }
        exclude = ['created_by',]
        widgets = {
            'branch':forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={}),
            'code':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Code','readonly':'readonly'}),
            'tag':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Asset Tag'}),
            'status':forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        }
```

**I don't know how to use request.session.get[] variable in form.py file **

Comment: Forms are request-unaware. You thus should pass these as parameter. The form does not know anything about the request.

Answer (score -1):

You can populate the initial data while initiating the form.

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/api/

```py
>>> initial = {"key": "value"}
>>> unbound_form = AssetTagForm(initial=initial)
```